# Concatenación Strings con StringBuilder Java

Tags: java

¿Cómo puedo concatenar 2 strings diferentes?

letra por letra sin usar `.concat` y `+` solo con `StringBuilder`, pongo ejemplo:

```java
String cadena1="Hola mundo", String cadena2="Adiós a todos"
```

Resultado esperado:

```
"HaOdLiAo sM UaN DtOos"
```

En mayúsculas, pongo las letras de la *cadena1* y en minúscula las letras de la *cadena2*, pero no es necesario es solo para que veáis a lo que me refiero

Comment: Bienvenido a SO. Creo que no entiendes muy bien como funcionamos. Aquí no vienes y dices "Cómo se hace esto?" y te lo dan hecho. Aquí debes ***investigar cómo se hace algo***, y si aun después de investigar no eres capaz de hacerlo o tienes un ***ERROR CONCRETO***, puedes venir, nos muestras lo que hiciste y te decimos dónde está el error. Pero venir y pedirnos que trabajemos para tí sin siquiera haberte esforzado un poquito... así no aprenderás nada. Así que por favor, intenta hacer algo primero. De paso, podrías leer [ask] y añadir un [mre] una vez que hayas intentado algo. Un saludo.

Comment: Buenas, bienvenido a StackOverlow y al mundo de la programación. Te recomiendo que eches un vistazo por nuestro [tour] para ver como realizar una pregunta de calidad, de esta manera consigues respuestas de calidad y buenas explicaciones. Puedes empezar por indicarnos el código que has intentado hacer, así cualquier error o problema que veamos te podemos explicar con tu propio ejemplo, todo ventajas.

Comment: Perdón no era mi intención causar esa molestia, no espero que trabaje nadie por mí, si fuera así no estaría estudiando ni tratando de formarme, era una duda que tenía para un ejercicio puesto que lo estoy intentando de mil maneras y no me sale , si no lo hubiese intentado ni preguntaría porque no entendería la solución, de todas formas gracias por el aporte, ya me he leído de la entrada de cómo preguntar para no volver a cometer estos errores, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Una forma de realizar lo que solicitas seria "atrapar" letra por letra y colocarla una por una. Una forma sencilla seria usar un bucle `for`, donde recorrerá cada `String` y cada letra para colocarlo una a una.

```
String cadena1="Hola mundo", cadena2="Adiós a todos";
        String letter;

        for (int i = 0; i < cadena1.length() + cadena2.length(); i++) {

            if (i < cadena1.length()) {
                letter = Character.toString(cadena1.charAt(i));
                System.out.print(letter.toUpperCase());
            } if (i < cadena2.length()){
                letter = Character.toString(cadena2.charAt(i));
                System.out.print(letter.toLowerCase());
            }
        }
```

Como puedes ver tenemos los dos `String` que tienes, colocamos un tercero que será el resultado final. En el bucle le indicamos que tiene que recorrer el igual de veces que la suma de espacios que ocupara nuestra variable `letter`, que es la suma de cada cadena. Y por ultimo dentro del bucle comprobamos que no nos salgamos del parámetro de la cadena, debido a que una es mas larga que la otra, sino comprobáramos nos aparecería un `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`. Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Buenas, muchas gracias por el aporte, van mas o menos por ahí los tiros pero de esta manera no me intercala carácter por carácter sigo dandole vueltas a ver si lo consigo, lo que yo estoy intentando es así :for(int i=0;i<cad1[i] ;i++){
   if (cad1[i] %2==0){
    System.out.print(entry1.replace(cad1[i], cad2[i]));
   }

Comment: Buenas, pues la verdad me pillas ahora sin saber que intentas. Viendo ese for ya se que te va a salir mal porque estas poniendo un parámetro array y se encuentra con un String, el cual no le pasa tampoco un numero valido. Te recomiendo como los dos comentarios de arriba que modifiques la pregunta y pongas tu código mas la explicación de que se debe lograr, así podremos ayudarte.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes iterar hasta el tamaño de la segunda cadena, usando su indice de la siguiente manera:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    String cadena1 = "Hola mundo";
    String cadena2 = "Adiós a todos";

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i <= cadena2.length(); i++) {

      if (i < cadena1.length()) {
        builder.append(Character.toUpperCase(cadena1.charAt(i)));
      }

      if (i < cadena2.length()) {
        builder.append(Character.toLowerCase(cadena2.charAt(i)));
      }
    }

    System.out.println(builder.toString());

  }
```

Esto te dará el siguiente resultado: *HaOdLiAó sM UaN DtOodos*